# Is it possible to set a global Blender preference so that all keyframed motion is linear by default?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I've been working on some animations recently, and I've noticed that I'm having poor luck with certain things, namely the fact that I don't really use Blender's graph editor very well.

One of the major issues that I have is pretty widespread among 3D graphics programs; when I create an animated object, it defaults to using a curved graph instead of a linear graph, which means that the most movement is at the middle of the animation, and stuff just practically stops near the beginning or the end. While this helps with organic camera movements or such, it's also not what I usually want. Can I set animation curves to default to linear?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, Its under *Editing > New F-Curve defaults*

[image]

*You might know this but just throwing it in additionally,* You can select the curve in Blender, at any ***two or more*** points and use <kbd>T</kbd> to change it to *Linear Interpolation* ([LERP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since Blender 2.8, it's at **Preferences** > **Animation** > **F-Curves** > **Default Interpolation**

[image]