# How do I make animations a steady speed?

Tags: animation

When I make an animation, it always starts out slow, then speeds up, then slows down at the end.  I cannot figure out how to fix this.

Comment: [Possibly related..](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/327/is-it-possible-to-set-a-global-blender-preference-so-that-all-keyframed-motion-i)

Answer (score 59):

Simply go to the Animation Screen Layout:

[image]

Now select *Channel > Extrapolation Mode > Linear Extrapolation* (shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>):

[image]

And that should fix it for you.

If you look at the *Graph Editor* before doing this, you will see:

[image]

The beginning and end of the curve are levelled out, this is what gives you the slowing down effect. It is called a *Bezier* function. When you choose 'Linear Extrapolation' it makes the curve a straight line:

[image]

The straight line is extended in both directions giving you continued animation, whereby if you choose Interpolation, *Key > Interpolation Mode > Linear* (shortcut <kbd>T</kbd>):

[image]

What starts off as curves...

[image]

...results in straight lines between keyframes with no extension beyond:

[image]

Comment: Just as an addendum, you can change the extrapolation mode by pressing `T` on your keyboard.

Comment: Hitting T changes interpolation mode. Extrapolation mode means how the motion continues outside the keyframes.

Comment: How do I "go to the Animation Screen Layout"?

Answer (score 8):

Go to the animation layout, and in the F-curve editor you can either hit <kbd>T</kbd>, to set the channel interpolation mode to linear, which affects the whole channel you have selected in the menu on the left side, or hit <kbd>V</kbd> to set the selected keyframe handles to vector mode. With setting single keyframe handles you have the possibility to use both kinds of interpolations.

Answer (score 1):

**Use a simple driver**

For a constant linear animation can make a driver that is a linear function of frame.

For example to rotate an object about x at one revolution (`2 * pi` radians) per second in a scene with 24 fps, for ever...

Type the following

```
#2 * pi * frame / 24
```

directly into the X rotation euler channel.

[image]

.  The hash `#` prefix signifies to blender it is a driver expression.

Once entered it will turn purple (driver color) and can be edited directly (removing the hash)

The variables `frame`, the current frame,  and `pi` are known to the driver namespace.

[image]

Note this could ofcourse be reduced to

```
pi * frame / 12
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed extrapolation mode to *Linear* instead of *Constant*. Animation is now at a constant speed with no smoothing in/out.

Comment: How do I "change the extrapolation mode to Linear"?