# How can I make an object spin without slowing down?

Tags: animation

I want to make an object spin without slowing down when animation is playing again.

Comment: Could you show the object's transformation Graph with all the keyframes of the interested animation?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1579/21825).

Answer (score 6):

In the graph editor, hit <kbd>T</kbd> and select Linear interpolation

[image]