# How do I make my walking animation to continuously move instead of stopping at the end of the frame

Tags: animation, rigging, timeline

[image]

As you can see, for some reason when my walking animation ends, why does it take longer for the character to move its legs apart again (that is from frame 0 to 40) compared to when the character moves apart its legs again from frame 80 to frame 120?

How do I continually get the character to move its legs repeatedly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make animations a steady speed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1579/how-do-i-make-animations-a-steady-speed)

Comment: Hi there, that is not what I am asking. See when the legs close at frame 80 it continues to move its legs. But at frame 160 it closes its legs and it stops and it starts again. Why does this happen?

Comment: @Jack232 are the first and last keyframes set to liner interpolation? If not, then this really is a duplicate.

Comment: The first and last keyframes are NOT set to linear interpolation. So you are suggesting I should set the first and last frame as linear interpolation, am I correct.

Also note that the first frame starts at frame 0 and the last frame is at frame 160 and frame 160 is supposed to have the legs together. I have decided to however end the frame at 159, did I do something wrong that is causing such an issue as mentioned in the topic of this post?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by changing how the interpolation is in the Graph editor.

1.Open up the graph editor and make sure you're on F-Curves;

2.Select all necessary keyframes and press Shift + E;

3.Now a little menu will appear, click on "Make Cyclic (F Modifier).

There, now your animation should be what you want.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem to work. Would you consider everything to be selected in the image (copy and paste the URL to get the image) https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKQ9t.png

Comment: Yea, everything seems fine. Have you tried different interpolation modes as well?

Comment: Yes I tried changing the interpolation modes and it doesn't suit the type of animation I want. Additionally the same issue still occurs where at the end of the frame the legs will stop moving. Am I doing something wrong or something?