# How to make a camera rotate on the spot?

Tags: animation, camera

what I need to do is so simple, it seems, I can't find anyone who has made a tutorial on it, and as such, I am quite stuck, as I'm new to blender.

What I need to do is rotate my camera 360 degrees on the spot about the X-axis as an animation (not just rotate it and move it about in 3D view, I know how to do that :P). The goal of this is that my camera is in a circular room-like environment, and I want an animation of the camera getting a complete look at every bit of the wall, not sure if that's relevant.

First time posting, any help is very much appreciated :-).

Answer (score 1):

1. Select your camera
2. Set a Keyframe by pressing <kbd>I</kbd> and selecting *Rotation*
3. Then move some frames forward (by clicking in the Timeline at the bottom)
4. Now rotate the camera by pressing <kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> and apply by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> 
   (Press <kbd>X</kbd> twice if you want to rotate around a local axis instead)
5. Set another keyframe like in step 2

That's all. Note that the movement won't be linear by default. If you want a linear movement instead, you need to change the interpolation mode of the keyframes. For that, you can have a look at the second part of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1580/55213) answer.
Hope it helps :)