# How do i disable the bezier function in 2.8?

Tags: animation

changing to 2.8 is a nightmare, everything's in a different spot now, where can i disable the Bezier function so my animations don't start slow, speed up, then slow down at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as before in the you can set the *Extrapolation Mode* for the channel in the Dope Sheet. For the keyframe you can set the *Interpolation Mode*. While the UI has changed the basic settings are the same. See: [How do I make animations a steady speed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1579/how-do-i-make-animations-a-steady-speed)

[image]

[image]