# How can I change the movement to Linear?

Tags: animation

I want that the animation always move linear how can I change that?
Thx for our help.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/327/is-it-possible-to-set-a-global-blender-preference-so-that-all-keyframed-motion-i

Answer (score 4):

1. Select the keyframes
2. *menu bar(header)* > Key > Interpolation Mode > Linear  (or shortcut <kbd>T</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>)

Comment: ..or, (in my release build, anyway), with the keys selected, you can just hit T in the timeline.