# Constant Interpolation when Auto keying

Tags: animation, keyframes, interpolation

I would like to animate using only constant interpolation. I know that I can change the interpolation with "T" or going to Timeline<Key<Interpolation, but every time I add a new keyframe the interpolation is Bezier.

How can I make it so every new frame is added with linear interpolation so that I don't need to keep setting new frames interpolation type manually?

Thank you.

Comment: It's in an older version of Blender, so it's actually on a near by page, but you lead me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: @ZakNelson it's there, on the newer answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/129537/

Comment: Yep I should have added you should look the second answer up, not the accepted one

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in Blender Prefences shown below:

[image]